# How to use UUID5 or UUID3 in Pyspark while adding a column?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to add a column to generate the unique number for the values in a column, but that randomly generated value should be fixed for every run.

For Ex: I have a df as

[image]

so every run the value of Harry should be xxyyzz and Misha should be gfddhh.
it should not produce any random number every time.

I used below code, but it's not working:

df = df.withColumn(""Unique_Name",uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS,'Name'))

it is giving error, I tried by converting it as str as well but still the error is same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import uuid

@F.udf
def create_uuid(name):
  return str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS,name))

df.withColumn("Unique_Name",create_uuid('Name')).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----+------------------------------------+
|name |Unique_Name                         |
+-----+------------------------------------+
|Harry|195d4fd9-f3e0-50fb-8e70-fa31078bdbf9|
|Misha|1f473375-c514-5495-8ef3-a079548ffcfd|
+-----+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Werner, Thanks for your quick response. It is working fine. However I was wondering if there is any other way to do the same like with map function.

Comment: @Madman if you want to use `map` you have to switch to rdds (at least in Python). Its possible: `df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS,x[0])))).toDF(["name", "Unique_Name"]).show()` but I would not recommend it

Comment: Thank you very much Werner for your detailed explanation.